# Play Store Error "You uploaded an APK that is signed with an insecure certificate"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, certificate, apk

I'm trying to upload a game to Play Store developed in Unity3D. I've already signed the apk using Unity's in built method with all the required parameters but I'm getting this error while trying to upload the APK on Play Store

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with an insecure certificate. RSA or DSA key size must be at least 2048 bits.
```

[image]

Comment: So get a cert that is 2048bits? Seems obvious enough...

Comment: signing process is automated in Unity and I don't have enough knowledge about these things. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You might be tried to upload the `debug` version of the app.

Comment: It's not the debug version. I've already signed the apk.

Comment: Suddenly started happening on my apps too. It's a change that happened few hours ago. I was able to update my apps yesterday.

Comment: So It's a bug in the Play Store?

Comment: Not sure. Waiting for more people to comment before I can make that assumption. Nothing has changed on my signing process.

Comment: Exactly. I've tried signing it like 10 times with different data and It's still the same.

Comment: I can also confirm that this is an issue only while submitting new apps. Old apps with same keys work correctly. I have not received any update from Google with regards to this change.

Comment: I get the same error when just trying to submit APK for a new app so can confirm that issue is still there. I also was able to upload APK after generating new keystore manually as @MaxTyt advised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having same mistake right now... New application too... It seems that we need to create keystrokes manually

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin" (where Java installed)
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

UPD: Yes it helped

Comment: Were you able to upload the apk after creating the keystore manually?

Comment: People can't just create new keys. All the existing apps would be rendered useless.

Comment: I was able to upload the apk after generating the keystore with this command. Thanks

Comment: If you add the key to your keystore manually, can you still use it with Unity?

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Google Support, and they did confirm that this was a bug. I did a live chat, and that person mentioned its a bug they started seeing today, and no action is required on my part. He couldn't tell me when it ll be fixed.

I noticed that I was able to upload an APK to an existing app with the non 2048 bit release key, and it only complained for a new app.

Comment: What exactly did they say? Can you link to more info?

Answer (score 3):

I just contacted Google Support about this and they said the following:

> Currently there is an internal bug which is the cause for this issue. I'm very sorry for the inconvenience, however there currently isn't any update on the matter as of yet.

They said they would email me with an update once there is one and I will post it here when I receive the email.

I would suggest not generating a new certificate if you've already published apps with the current one you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Google fixed this bug! It's working fine now as earlier.